# All our scheduled queries have been failing with `Error code 3 : Incompatible table partitioning specification.` since 2019-04-23 at 8PM UTC

Tags: google-bigquery

Our scheduled queries have been running for months without any hiccups, but starting from 8pm UTC on 2019-04-23, they failed with the following error, and they are still failing very often 36 hours later.

> 11:00:01 PM   Error code 3 : Incompatible table partitioning specification. Destination table exists with partitioning specification interval(type:DAY,field:), but transfer target partitioning specification is interval(type:DAY,field:). Please retry after updating either the destination table or the transfer partitioning specification.
>
> 11:00:00 PM   Starting to process the query job with parameter @run_date=2019-04-23.
>
> 11:00:00 PM   Dispatched run to data source with id 538824528883320

The following screenshot shows that some runs are ok (but none of our queries had successful runs today):

[image: runs]

We tried redeploying the queries, but they still fail on the first run. Hitting `Retry` generates the same error too.

---

**Update 1**

So while we wait for Google folks to fix the bug, we found a workaround, as detailed in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131266091.

The solution was to re-create all the destination tables of our schedule queries without `--require_partition_filter` and `--time_partitioning_expiration`.

I really mean re-creating the tables. Updating the table configurations with `bq update --norequire_partition_filter --time_partitioning_expiration 0` does not fix the problem.

Comment: Have encountered the same error in past few days. I am assuming it is a site wide issue and not project specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/131266091) and should be fixed soon.